# Symfony 2 case-insensitive routing

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently developing an application using Symfony 2 and would like my routes to be case-insensitive.

I've included an example route. This only matches /some_url/. I'd like this to match any variation on that pattern. eg. /Some_url/, /SOME_URL/ etc...

```
some_route:
    pattern:  /some_url/
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:Action }
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: It is not a response to your question, but you need to know that this kind of routing strategy is very very bad for SEO. In regards of search engines, you will have a lot of **duplicate contents** (ie: many different URLs, serving the same content).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I realised that and was planning on redirecting all the variations. I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: I have a solution to a similar question that uses 301 redirects to avoid SEO issues http://stackoverflow.com/a/34959306/1153227

Comment: What about using a canonical URL, regardless of whatever case-insensitive route is provided? –  The crawler would store the content just once, and imho would solve the SEO issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
some_route:
    pattern:   /{some_url}/
    defaults:  { _controller: Bundle:Controller:Action }
    requirements:
        some_url:  (?i:some_url)
```

but as already mentioned in the comments, this is a bad practice

Comment: Is `?i:` from PCRE? I'm used to set case-insensitive with **"i"** (`~regex~i`), but apparently Symfony doesn't seem to support regexps that specify delimiters (here "~")

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    some_route:
        pattern:  /some_url/
        defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:Action }

    _Some_route:
        pattern:  /Some_url/
        defaults: { _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect, route: some_route }

    __SOME_route:
        pattern:  /SOME_URL/
        defaults: { _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect, route: some_route }
```

You can create some routes for diferents case sensitive math, and redirect at some route with this instructions in the default property

```
defaults: { _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect, route: some_route }
```

I hope this helps!
    ...

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for contributing! Answers are more helpful if you can explain how they work or what you think the issue is that the OP was having and that your answer addresses. The better your answer, the more likely it will be upvoted and/or accepted.

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does this approach scale for **all** variations of a single route, and afterwards for **multiple** routes?